# How can real duplicate a dictionary or a list array?

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, dictionary

I have a Dictionary

```
Dim List4x As Dictionary(Of Byte, List(Of Byte)) = DuplicateDic(ByteList4)

Public Shared Function DuplicateDic(ByVal List As Dictionary(Of Byte, List(Of Byte))) As Dictionary(Of Byte, List(Of Byte))
    Dim kv As New Dictionary(Of Byte, List(Of Byte))
    For Each itm As KeyValuePair(Of Byte, List(Of Byte)) In List
        kv.Add(itm.Key, itm.Value)
    Next
    Return kv
End Function
```

If i remove one by one items in old list my new list clearing..

How can real duplicate a dictionary or a list array?

Thanks

Comment: A `List(Of T)` is a reference type (a class). You have to create a completely new list for the new dictionary. You could either iterate each list like you do with your dictionary, or you could make a [**deep copy**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37085471/3740093).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a new list, otherwise both lists are same and if you remove it from list 2 you will also remove it from list 1 because `List(Of T)` is a reference type. You can use [this list constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Public Shared Function DublicateList(ByVal List As Dictionary(Of Byte, List(Of Byte))) As Dictionary(Of Byte, List(Of Byte))
    Dim kv As New Dictionary(Of Byte, List(Of Byte))
    For Each itm As KeyValuePair(Of Byte, List(Of Byte)) In List
        Dim newList As New List(Of Byte)(itm.Value)  ' <----- HERE !!!
        kv.Add(itm.Key, newList)
    Next
    Return kv
End Function
```